# Conditional operator in concatenated string

Tags: java

I'd like know why the following program throws a NPE

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer testInteger = null;
    String test = "test" + testInteger == null ? "(null)" : testInteger.toString();
}
```

while this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer testInteger = null;
    String test = "test" + (testInteger == null ? "(null)" : testInteger.toString());
}
```

doesn't. It's certainly a priority problem and I'm curious how the concatenation works inside.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an example of the importance of understanding [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

You need the parentheses otherwise it is interpreted as follows:

```
String test = ("test" + testInteger) == null ? "(null)" : testInteger.toString();
```

See [here](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php) for a list of operators and their precedence. Also note the warning at the top of that page:

> Note: Use explicit parentheses when there is even the possibility of confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Without the brackets it's doing this effectively:
`String test = ("test" + testInteger) == null ? "(null)" : testInteger.toString();`
Which results in an NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's evaluated as `"test" + testInteger` (which is `"testnull"`, and therefore NOT null), meaning your `testInteger == null` test will never return true.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add the parenthesis. Here is a working example which produces "http://localhost:8080/catalog/rest"

```
public static String getServiceBaseURL(String protocol, int port, String hostUrl, String baseUrl) {
    return protocol + "://" + hostUrl + ((port == 80 || port == 443) ? "" : ":" + port) + baseUrl;
}
```